# How to Force Java to Print out Large Numbers without the use of Long or Double?

Tags: java

So I'm currently using this code to calculate the population growth:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PopulationGrowth
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalP = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter Starting Populatino: ");
        int startingP = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Growth Rate: ");
        int growthR = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter amount of time it takes to achieve this growth: ");
        int timeI = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Total Amount of Time: ");
        int totalTime = sc.nextInt();

        int intervals = totalTime / timeI; 
        for(int i = 0; i < intervals; i++)
        {
            long finalP = startingP * growthR;
            System.out.println(finalP);
            growthR += growthR;
        }

    }

}
```

It works fine, but if I input a large number I get this output:

```
65536000
131072000
262144000
524288000
1048576000
2097152000
-100663296
-201326592
-402653184
-805306368
-1610612736
1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

**Note, if you look at my code you could see that I tried using the long type, but unfortunately, that didn't work**

### My Question:

Is there a way for Java to print a large number without the use of long or double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using the long type, but unfortunately, that didn't work

```
long finalP = startingP * growthR;
```

As long as `startingP` and `growthR` are still `int`, this calculation will still be done using 32 bit integers (and only converted to 64 bit integers afterwards, when you already encountered overflow).

You can change all your variables to `long`. Then you will be able to work with larger numbers, but eventually those will also overflow.

> Is there a way for Java to print a large number without entering the negatives and ultimately the 0s

Depending on your application needs, you may need to look at either infinite-precision `BigInteger` or floating point numbers such as `double` (which can represent much larger quantities, but with a loss of precision in the lower digits -- that seems acceptable here).

Comment: I changed all my variable types to long, but unfortunately, it still reaches the negatives and 0s. Note : The Value of the print increase dramatically but it still goes into the negative

Comment: I think you want `double`.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem, I will accept your answer!